# Stop images stretching when adding them to a bootstrap card etc when they are smaller than their parent div

Tags: html, css

(New to SO and fairly new to coding)

Is there a unique class or HTML/CSS code that i can use to prevent this from happening to preserve image resolution and responsiveness?

As you can see i have added the container class to the outermost div to center the cards and the .img-fluid/.img-responsive classes for responsiveness. This helped a lot but there's something missing that i can't quite put my finger on.

```
<div class="card-deck container center-block">    

            <div class="card">

                <img id="web-design" class="card-img-top img-fluid image-responsive" src="./img/html_css_javascript.png" alt="Card image cap">

                <div class="card-block">

                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>

                </div>

            </div>

        <div class="card">

                <img id="bootstrap" class="card-img-top img-fluid image-responsive" src="./img/bootstrap.png" alt="Card image cap">

                <div class="card-block">

                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>

                </div>

        </div>

        <div class="card">

                <img id="j-query" class="crd-img-top img-responsive img-fluid" src="./img/jquery.png" alt="Card image cap">

                <div class="card-block">

                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>

                </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are a couple of issues with your question. If you avoid these common mistakes it will make people want to assist you more in the future.  First you need to mention versions when necessary.  Bootstrap3 is different from Bootstrap 4, and even with in v4 there's differences between alpha6 and the recently released beta.  Secondly, pasting large chunks of code is unnecessary.  If the issue is with a "card", we just need to see the code for that.  We don't need to see 3 cards which all have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured it out! Found a great tutorial on this.

Adding the following html code to individual image tags (using the width and height of the cards specified in the documentation) i was able to preserve resolution and responsiveness.

```
 width="190" height="200"
```

Comment: Kudos for solving your own problem.  But your answer is not clear enough, and if you find information in the docs, please try to quote the necessary part and provide a link.

Comment: This assumes you know the dimensions of every image, which is not useful if the images change. For example, if one is 190x200 and another is 200x200. Basically what is needed is for bootstrap to stop resizing the images upwards, while allowing downsizing.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution add

```
.card-img-top{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Bootstrap, you can add the `h-100` class to your `<img>` element:

```html
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top h-100" src="yourimage.png" alt="">
</div>
```

This will keep the size of the image element at 100% as per [the docs on Sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/):

> Easily make an element as wide or as tall (relative to its parent) with our width and height utilities. [...] Includes support for 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100% by default. Modify those values as you need to generate different utilities here.